# Java check if string is null or empty

Tags: java, string, nullpointerexception

I got a few strings and I perform some checking before using the values on the charts. Here are my codes:

```
for (int j = 0; j < shareByTypeList.size(); j++) {
            if (j == 0) {
                facebookShare = shareByTypeList.get(j).getTotalShare();
            } else if (j == 1) {
                googleplusShare = shareByTypeList.get(j).getTotalShare();
            } else {
                twitterShare = shareByTypeList.get(j).getTotalShare();
            }
        }

        if (facebookShare != null && !facebookShare.isEmpty()
                && twitterShare != null && !twitterShare.isEmpty()
                && googleplusShare != null && !googleplusShare.isEmpty()) {
            txtDisplayFacebook.setText(facebookShare);
            txtDisplayTwitter.setText(twitterShare);
            txtDisplayGooglePlus.setText(googleplusShare);
            totalShare = Integer.parseInt(facebookShare)
                    + Integer.parseInt(googleplusShare)
                    + Integer.parseInt(twitterShare);
            txtDisplayShareAmt.setText(String.valueOf(totalShare));
        }
```

I am checking if the string itself is null or empty before parse them into Integer. However, I am still getting NullPointerException at the if statement there. When I try to print out the facebookShare, it just appear empty at the console. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

The stack trace:

```
12-30 13:53:39.787: E/AndroidRuntime(1787): java.lang.NullPointerException
12-30 13:53:39.787: E/AndroidRuntime(1787):     at nyp.edu.eneighbourhood.EventDetailChart.onCreateView(EventDetailChart.java:191)
12-30 13:53:39.787: E/AndroidRuntime(1787):     at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1504)
12-30 13:53:39.787: E/AndroidRuntime(1787):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:942)
12-30 13:53:39.787: E/AndroidRuntime(1787):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1121)
12-30 13:53:39.787: E/AndroidRuntime(1787):     at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
12-30 13:53:39.787: E/AndroidRuntime(1787):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1484)
12-30 13:53:39.787: E/AndroidRuntime(1787):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:482)
12-30 13:53:39.787: E/AndroidRuntime(1787):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentStatePagerAdapter.java:163)
12-30 13:53:39.787: E/AndroidRuntime(1787):     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1073)
12-30 13:53:39.787: E/AndroidRuntime(1787):     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.setCurrentItemInternal(ViewPager.java:555)
12-30 13:53:39.787: E/AndroidRuntime(1787):     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.setCurrentItemInternal(ViewPager.java:514)
12-30 13:53:39.787: E/AndroidRuntime(1787):     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.setCurrentItem(ViewPager.java:495)
12-30 13:53:39.787: E/AndroidRuntime(1787):     at nyp.edu.eneighbourhood.EventDetailMain$2.onTabSelected(EventDetailMain.java:42)
12-30 13:53:39.787: E/AndroidRuntime(1787):     at com.android.internal.app.ActionBarImpl.selectTab(ActionBarImpl.java:512)
12-30 13:53:39.787: E/AndroidRuntime(1787):     at com.android.internal.app.ActionBarImpl$TabImpl.select(ActionBarImpl.java:893)
12-30 13:53:39.787: E/AndroidRuntime(1787):     at com.android.internal.widget.ScrollingTabContainerView$TabClickListener.onClick(ScrollingTabContainerView.java:502)
12-30 13:53:39.787: E/AndroidRuntime(1787):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3620)
12-30 13:53:39.787: E/AndroidRuntime(1787):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14292)
12-30 13:53:39.787: E/AndroidRuntime(1787):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
12-30 13:53:39.787: E/AndroidRuntime(1787):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
12-30 13:53:39.787: E/AndroidRuntime(1787):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-30 13:53:39.787: E/AndroidRuntime(1787):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4512)
12-30 13:53:39.787: E/AndroidRuntime(1787):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-30 13:53:39.787: E/AndroidRuntime(1787):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-30 13:53:39.787: E/AndroidRuntime(1787):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:982)
12-30 13:53:39.787: E/AndroidRuntime(1787):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:749)
12-30 13:53:39.787: E/AndroidRuntime(1787):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-30 13:53:49.334: I/Process(1787): Sending signal. PID: 1787 SIG: 9
```

Comment: Paste stack trace? It must be different line..

Comment: The first part is only assigning to 1 of the 3 shares. If `j == 0` and you assign the facebook share, would the google and twitter ones be null at the if?

Comment: It's highly unlikely that the NPE happens in the `if` statement. Please show the exact stack trace and annotate your code with the relevant line numbers.

Comment: Which line is line 191?

Comment: Can you please tell us which line is null pointer occuring?

Comment: It's the if statement where I check if the string is null. This line:  if (facebookShare != null && !facebookShare.isEmpty()

Comment: Can you specify exactly which line is line 191, please...

Comment: Do you give the 3 variables default values at all?

Comment: Nope but I solved it already. I solved it by separating three of the variables to perform a check

Comment: I've posted it already. Thanks all for the helps :)

Comment: Down voter mind to explain?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by separating 3 variables to perform a check then set the value to textview:

```
if (facebookShare != null && !facebookShare.isEmpty()) {
            txtDisplayFacebook.setText(facebookShare);
        } else if (twitterShare != null && !twitterShare.isEmpty()) {
            txtDisplayTwitter.setText(twitterShare);
        } else if (googleplusShare != null && !googleplusShare.isEmpty()) {
            txtDisplayGooglePlus.setText(googleplusShare);
        }

        if (!txtDisplayFacebook.getText().equals("0")
                && !txtDisplayTwitter.getText().equals("0")
                && !txtDisplayGooglePlus.getText().equals("0")) {
            totalShare = Integer.parseInt(facebookShare)
                    + Integer.parseInt(googleplusShare)
                    + Integer.parseInt(twitterShare);
            txtDisplayShareAmt.setText(String.valueOf(totalShare));
        }
```